# InkCanvas в BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf

В данный момент я перевожу так

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "test.jpg");
FileStream CreateFile = File.Create(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\test.jpg");
RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)DrawField.Width, (int)DrawField.Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);
rtb.Render(DrawField);
JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
encoder.Save(CreateFile);
CreateFile.Close();
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
image.DecodePixelWidth = 150;
image.DecodePixelHeight = 150;
image.UriSource = new Uri(filePath);
image.EndInit();
Img.Source = image;
```

в BitmapImage перевожу что бы изменять размер картинки что бы после работать с ним Только вот у меня есть ошибка из-за чего я не могу повторно загрузить картинку как это можно исправить

Comment: Что именно за ошибка, и в какой строке возникает? Вам обязательно это в файл сохранять?

Comment: @aepot проблема в том что создав изменный файл повторно он не грузиться на image. насчет сохранения точно не знаю как лучше я делал это для того что бы уменьшить размер картинки. пробую написать нейроную сеть считывающую картинки